# is it possible to write an algorithm in zbase32?

Tags: apex, batch, developer-console, developer, algorithm

I have a request to generate unique codes through an algorithm.

1. take a unique number from a sequence (maximum value 2 ^ 30)
2. ZBase32 encoding is used to encrypt the number.
   The encoding alphabet is as follows:
   YBNDRFG8EJKMCPQXOT1UWISZA345H769

can you help me in case it can be done?
thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Right now, your question doesn't fit our format here: we look to see *what you've tried so far* and *where you're stuck*, that is, a specific problem in your work. Additionally, it's not clear how your question relates to the Salesforce platform.

Comment: Could you take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic], and then [edit] your post to add more information?

Answer (score 1):

A naive implementation for this would be:

```
static String[] baseMap = 'YBNDRFG8EJKMCPQXOT1UWISZA345H769'.split('');
public String encodeZbase32(Integer source) {
    return 
        baseMap[(source >> 25)&31] +
        baseMap[(source >> 20)&31] +
        baseMap[(source >> 15)&31] +
        baseMap[(source >> 10)&31] +
        baseMap[(source >>  5)&31] +
        baseMap[(source      )&31];
    
}
public Integer decodeZBase32(String source) {
    String[] bits = source.split('');
    return
        (baseMap.indexOf(bits))<<25 |
        (baseMap.indexOf(bits))<<20 |
        (baseMap.indexOf(bits))<<15 |
        (baseMap.indexOf(bits))<<10 |
        (baseMap.indexOf(bits))<< 5 |
        (baseMap.indexOf(bits));
}
```

I leave it up to you to decide if you need the trailing 0 bits at the end, or any other features.